# Who can win the bowling match？

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

There are $n$ bowling pins arranged from left to right, numbered from $1$ to $n$ in the order they are standing. Two people throw bowling balls and hit them in turn. Each time they hit a pin, they knock over that pin, and its two adjacent pins. (If you hit pin number $x$, then pins $x$, $x-1$ and $x+1$ will fall, if they had not fallen earlier). The player who hits the last pin wins. Who can win?

For example, if you hit pin 3, and pins 2 and 4 are all standing, you will knock down pins 2, 3, and 4. If you hit the 3th pin, but only the 3rd and 4th pin is standing, you will knock down the 3rd and 4th pins. If you hit pin 3, and the 4th and 2nd pins are not standing, you will only knock down pin 3.

I guess when $n\ge 4$, if $n$ is an odd number, the first hand can hit the middle three, and then mirror the operation of the second hand, and the first hand will win. If n is even, it seems a little complicated?

Comment: Do you mean: The player who hits the last bowling bottle standing wins?

Comment: @garondal  Sorry sir, I am not good at English and I  used translate machine to communicate ,I will edit it.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand, how about drawing a picture?

Comment: Ok, understood. What about when you have bowling balls $1,2,3,4$ all standing and you hit $1$? Then only number $1$ will fall, right? I think I understood what is going on here, and this should be recursively solvable.

Comment: What do you mean by "adjacent three"? If, say the standing pins are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, and I hit 5, which ones fall?

And are players permitted to miss? I presume not?

Comment: @Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer Sir,if you hit No.1,then both No.1 and No.2 will fall.

Comment: @chenyueyue Then I'm confused. If my pins look like :$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ in that order, then I'm not sure why only $2$ falls when you say "the adjacent $3$ will fall". This probably needs a diagram, but I'm still convinced that working recursively will solve the problem, whatever it is.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer go ahead and solve it then, you can't lose anything by trying.

Comment: @Sarvesh Ravichandran Sir, this may be the fault of the translation software

Comment: @chenyueyue See if you can put up whatever is written in your original language. If someone can make anything of it here, we can translate well and answer this question properly. I don't want to indulge in guesswork, and want to make sure the others do not as well.

Comment: "adjacent three" only on the left, or on both sides of the *hit*, subject to a maximum of $3$ ?

Comment: @true blue anil both sides of the hit,a maximum of 3,sir.

Comment: Then why only 1 and 2 when you hit 1 ? Also, is it a question from a book, etc or are *you* trying to make a question ?

Comment: @true blue anil sir, I get this question from a chinese BBS,someone ask for it.If you hit x,x and x-1 and x+1 will fall.

Comment: Sorry, as it stands, the question is inconsistent, so can't be answered.

Comment: @true blue anil  TY,sir, sincerely apologize for the unclear details I showed.

Comment: See "octal games" for generalizations.  This one (if I'm reading your description correctly) is known as "Dawson's Chess".

Comment: The rules are simple: On a player's turn, he aims at any standing pin $x$, which will fall; and if an adjacent pin ($x-1$ or $x+1$) is still standing, it will also fall.  (So at most $3$ pins will fall.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple Python script to calculate the nim-value of this game (i.e., the size of the equivalent Nim heap) for each starting number of pins.  The precise rule I'm using is that you can knock down 2 or 3 pins from the end of a row, or any adjacent 3 from the middle.

```
def mex(vals):
  # return the minimum value excluded from `vals`
  v = 0
  while v in vals: v += 1
  return v

def nimVal(n, cache = { 0:0, 1:1 }):
  if n in cache: return cache[n]
  vals = [nimVal(n-2, cache)] # knock down 2 pins on the end
  if n >= 3:
    vals.append(nimVal(n-3, cache)) # knock down 3 pins on the end
    for m in range(1, n-3):
      # knock down 3 pins in the middle, leaving m on one side
      # and n-m-3 on the other
      vals.append(nimVal(m, cache) ^ nimVal(n-m-3, cache))
  ret = cache[n] = mex(vals)
  return ret
```

Running this script shows the periodicity to be $34$, and that the second player wins when the initial number of pins is sufficiently large and is equal to $4$, $8$, $20$, $24$, or $28$ (mod $34$).  In fact "sufficiently large" isn't that large... the only deviations from this rule are $N=14$ and $N=34$, which are also second-player wins.

Comment: TY,sir,I have learned the "sg function" and know how to play to win.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: *This answer is incorrect, see mjqxxxx's answer. I'll edit again if I figure out how to fix.*

---

I'm interpreting the question as follows. There are pins numbered 1, ..., 100. On your turn you can select any pin that's still standing, and knock down that pin and the pins immediately adjacent to it. (If the adjacent pins are already down, then they stay down.) For example, you can select pin 3 and knock down 2, 3, 4. The pins at the ends only have one adjacent pin each, so selecting pin 1 knocks down 1 and 2, and selecting pin 100 knocks down 99 and 100. There are two players alternating turns and the winner is the player who knocks down the last pin. And to clarify, you cannot select a pin that's already down, otherwise the player who's about to lose can select the same pin over and over and the game would not end.

The main observation is that the solution must also consider the *misère* version – same rules, except the player who knocks down the last pin loses.

Let's introduce some notation: $G(n)$ for the game starting with $n$ pins, and $G^*(n)$ for the *misère* version starting with $n$ pins. So for example, $G(1)$, $G(2)$, $G(3)$ are evidently wins for the first player, while $G^*(3)$ is also a win for the first player. $G(4)$ is a loss for the first player while $G^*(4)$ is a win for the first player.

Let $W$ be the set of all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $G(n)$ is a win for the first player and $G^*(n)$ is a loss for the first player; let $L$ be the set of all $n$ such that $G(n)$ is a loss and $G^*(n)$ is a win; and let $B$ be the set of all $n$ such that both $G(n)$ and $G^*(n)$ are wins. We have $W = \{1, 2, 6, 7, ...\}$, $L = \{0, 4, 8, ...\}$, $B = \{3, 5, ...\}$.

Now let's say we're in the middle of a game and we're looking at a board with $k$ groups of consecutive pins, with lengths $\ell_1$, ..., $\ell_k$. <s>Then which player will win the game is determined by which of the classes $W$, $L$, $B$ the lengths $\ell_i$ belong to. I'll leave it to you to prove this lemma:</s>

**Lemma**. If at least one of the $\ell_i$'s is in $B$, then the next person to play wins iff an odd number of $\ell_i$'s are in $B$. Otherwise, the next person to play wins iff an odd number of $\ell_i$'s are in $W$.

This completely solves the game (i.e. tells us how to play perfectly) as long as we can figure out these classes $W$, $L$, $B$. And we can, by recursion. Armed with the Lemma, any first move we can make in $G(n)$ or $G^*(n)$ reduces us to the result of $G(m)$ or $G^*(m)$ for one or more $m < n$.

Thus, $G(n)$ is a win for the first player iff $n-2 \in L$ or $\exists j$ ($0 \le j \le n-3$) such that $j$ and $n-3-j$ are in the same class. This generalizes the observation the OP made: If $n$ is odd, then $\exists j$ such that $j = n-3-j$ which means the first player wins $G(n)$.

Likewise, $G^*(n)$ is a win for the first player iff $n-2 \in W$ or $\exists j$ ($0 \le j \le n-3$) such that $j \in L$ and $n-3-j \in W$.

Finally, doing some computations, we find
\begin{align*}
W &= \{1, 2, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 20, 21, 25, ...\} \\
L &= \{0, 4, 8, 14\} \\
B &= \{3, 5, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, ...\}
\end{align*}
and we notice that for $n > 14$ the behavior is periodic with period 14. This can be proven by casework, tedious but not very complicated.

So we conclude that the first player wins the game starting with any number of pins except for 4, 8, and 14.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the game described is "Dawson's Chess".  It's known to be periodic with period 34.  Dawson himself seemed to believe it had period 14, but was mistaken: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/papers/unpublished/DawsonChess.pdf

Comment: @mjqxxxx huh that's really interesting, I must've made a similar mistake that Dawson did. I hadn't heard of this problem before. You're definitely right, $n = 20$ is a win for the second player. My lemma gives the wrong answer on 3+5 and 3+9 which messes everything else up. Roughly speaking my thinking on the case of two piles of length $b_1$, $b_2 \in B$ was "each pile individually you can choose to force either a win or a loss, so the second player to decide can just mirror the first" but that breaks down at the end because the first player can just move 3+5 to 3+3, d'oh!

Comment: @mjqxxxx In any case I've stricken everything, will edit again if I figure out how to fix it. thanks